# React-Router-Dom not working on firebase Hosting

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router-dom

I configured a route that takes 2 parameters:

```
<Route path="/:uid/:region" element={<Upgrade />} />
```

Locally , it works correctly and when I access the link with the params it works fine, but when I host the web app on firebase, the same link no longer works and it returns 404 not found.

Comment: Check https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#firebase

Comment: Fixed , thank you for your answer but actually i had to make the app a single web page

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**

You should set the web app as a single web page app :

During Firebase init , when selecting Hosting , it asks you some question , one of these questions is if you want the web app to be a single web page ( redirect all urls to index.html ) , the correct answer here is Yes